# Antonym of "Towards" contained in one word?

Tags: antonyms

Antonym of "Towards" contained in one word?

The only antonym that I can think of is "Away From", but that is two words.

Comment: If *away from* has the exact meaning you need, why does there have to be a single-word equivalent?

Comment: I am trying to make a short sentence. Eliminating a word would aid that goal.

Comment: Off: From a place or position: drove off.

Comment: Can you give us your sentence, and some context, please? It would help us give you a good answer! :)

Comment: @Araucaria `x can go towards y, or, x can go away from y.`  As said; I am aiming towards simple sentences empathizing a logical structure.

Comment: If you co-ordinate the locative complements of *GO*, then you could have '*X can go towards or from Y*'. Might be slightly better as *X can lead to or from Y* if the verb *lead* suits your context? Or perhaps the verb *HEAD*?

Comment: @Araucaria as per the suggestion, does `x can go towards y, or, x can go offwards y.` work?

Comment: @Akiva I'm afraid not, because *offwards* is an intransitive preposition, so you can't use a noun afterwards :(

Comment: @Araucaria What about "Awaywards"?

Comment: @Akiva: Awayward(s) is an obsolete word.

Comment: @ermanen Can I make it relevant again? What made it obsolete?

Comment: @Akiva Was that comment for Ermanem, maybe?

Comment: @Akiva *Awaywards* is also intransitive though, I'm afraid ...

Comment: IF your sentence is actually "*X can go towards y, or x can go away from y*" then it can be shortened to: "*X can go towards Y or away.*"

Answer (score 2):

There is the adverb ***offward*** (*offwards*) but it is specifically used to mean the direction away from the land and towards the sea. Though, you can use the word in other contexts too but it is not that common.

> :  off or away from something as to direction or position; specifically :  off or away from the shore *the deck was canting*
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offward